# Any idea what are "? fp ... & prvtof ... & poru " in a url?

Tags: url, web

Someone tried to enter my site with the following query string, any idea where does he come from?

```
?fp=
zjk78g29gT2pDmAKaEubOPkA7nJMuAzYE/1g==
&prvtof=
PcSsxAS2f/lKKBhrJ2elmK7R7zIwzwbLKrWS45ffE
&poru=B7O5/gnxOl3WKyypX7ceMgmdTXuoFtNF0+UwWbG3xlACHMj7p52Tyg
```

Comment: Ever figure out what that was??

Comment: nope- never found out

Comment: Also interested if it is anyhow dangerous to follow that link?

Comment: If you decode first arg from base 64 it looks like password attempt